# Melhora de performance - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, desempenho

Tenho 3 tabelas:

[usuarios] 1 ----------- n [avaliacoes] n --------- 1 [itens]

Onde a avaliação pode ser positiva(avaliacao: *true*) ou negativa(avaliacao: *false*), eu preciso de um método que retorne todos os itens que o usuário gostou e não gostou... Para isto fiz o seguinte método no modelo do usuário:

```
# Retorna o numero de Likes
def likes
  itens = Array.new
  self.avaliacoes.where( avaliacao: true ).includes(:item).each do |avaliacao|
    itens << avaliacao.item
  end
  return itens
end
```

O mesmo principio foi adotado para o método para o método *dislike*

A idéia é fazer isso com muitos usuários, o problema é que está demorando consideravelmente para retornar os dados. Tem algum jeito de melhorar a *performance* desse trecho de código? Alguma estrutura que eu possa manter no servidor, pois essa consulta é executado muitas vezes mais de uma vez por usuário...

Comment: Você já pensou em usar `has many through`? Assim você poderia fazer `@usuario.itens` diretamente, sem precisar do `.each`. [Veja](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Comment: Verifica se a tabela avaliacoes possui índice para usuario_id e outro para item_id.

Comment: @Andrey, eu ja tenho `has many through` mas eu ainda preciso verificar se a avaliação foi positiva ou negativa. Tem como fazer isso?

Comment: Será que daria algo como `self.itens.joins(:avaliacoes).where("avaliacoes.avaliacao = ?", true)`?

Answer (score 2):

Tive a ideia de tentar fazer diretamente no banco para simplificar o processo e modifiquei a função para:

```
def likes
  query = "SELECT itm.id
           FROM   avaliacoes av INNER JOIN itens itm ON av.item_id = itm.id
           WHERE  avaliacao is true and
                usuario_id = #{self.id}"
  Usuario.connection.execute(query).to_set
end
```

Tive uma melhora de 0.2 segundos na média... Estou colocando como resposta pois acho que não da para melhorar mais do que isso, mas se alguém quiser me provar o contrario a resposta será muito bem vinda!

Comment: Eu uso o método de `like` e `dislike` para achar a similaridade entre usuários. Matutando aqui, acho que uma solução melhor seria montar uma matriz[][] de similaridade de usuário x usuário e deixar como atributo do modelo do Usuário, assim quando precisasse seria somente usar matriz[user1.id - 1][user2.id - 1]. O que vocês acham?

Answer (score 0):

não seria menos custoso se vc fizesse paginado ? 
Você pode usar a biblioteca 
https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate 
assim vai retornar os itens paginado acredito que vai diminuir o tempo da busca.